# Deep linking into ride.lyft PWA

Tags: deep-linking, progressive-web-apps

I'm trying to create a deep link for a predefined ride into Lyft's PWA at ride.lyft.com

I couldn't find any specific documentation for this, just for Lyft's API, so I started to experiment.

I created a session and defined a pickup & destination. This is how the window looks [image: Lyft PWA]

Now the URL for this page seems to contaiin everything I need with the pickup and destination:
https://ride.lyft.com/request?pickup=Balboa%20Park%20Station%2C%20401%20Geneva%20Ave%2C%20San%20Francisco%2C%20CA%2094112%2C%20USA@37.7215968,-122.447511&destination=San%20Francisco%20International%20Airport%20(SFO)%2C%20San%20Francisco%2C%20CA%2094128%2C%20USA@37.6213129,-122.3789554

But when I open this URL (after validating my phone number if needed) I get a different pickup location.

Any idea how to fix this?
Would be happy to just find the official documentation.

Comment: I would also ask the [Lyft discussion board](https://developer.lyft.com/discuss).

Comment: Submitted a ticket with Lyft concerning the issue. They said they will forward to engineering. Maybe someone will join the discussion and clarify. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I think it has something to do with the fact that the URI encoding is messing up your latitude and longitude coordinates.

The unescaped URL looks like this:

https://www.lyft.com/auth?next=https://www.lyft.com/mobile/start&pickup=Balboa+Park+Station,+401+Geneva+Ave,+San+Francisco,+CA+94112,+USA@37.7215968,-122.447511&destination=San+Francisco+International+Airport+(SFO),+San+Francisco,+CA+94128,+USA@37.6213129,-122.3789554

But your version looks like this:

https://www.lyft.com/auth?next=https%3A//www.lyft.com/mobile/start&pickup=Balboa+Park+Station%2C+401+Geneva+Ave%2C+San+Francisco%2C+CA+94112%2C+USA%4037.7215968%2C-122.447511&destination=San+Francisco+International+Airport+%28SFO%29%2C+San+Francisco%2C+CA+94128%2C+USA%4037.6213129%2C-122.3789554

If you take a look at the latitude and longitude coordinates, they're something like this:

`USA%4037.7215968%2C-122.447511` and `USA%4037.6213129%2C-122.3789554`

I'm guessing that Lyft have a bug in their code and they're not properly parsing the URL when you use deep linking. They should be using `decodeURIComponent(URI)` to properly parse the data out of the URL.